# Anaconda Navigator won't Open After Install

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I installed the latest version of Anaconda (2022.10-Windows-x86_64) and the navigator isn't launching. When I click the shortcut in my Start menu, or if I start the application directly from the application, the command window pops up for an instant then disappears and that's about all that happens.

When I launch the Anaconda prompt, I get an immediate error message that says "Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string."

See screen shot:
[image]

I get the same error message if I enter any command.  Jupyter and Python both launch and work, but navigator does not and I cannot install any packages or dependencies. Any thoughts?

Comment: what command are you issuing at the terminal? I thought normally you start navigator from the start menu...

Comment: Any command gives the same error message as the one posted above.